# Classify 3-sheeted covering spaces of $S^1 \times S^1$

Tags: algebraic-topology, covering-spaces

I know there are some similar questions to this, but I have a theorem for clasification of covering spaces:

Given a topological space $B$ (path conncted and locally path connected).

$\phi: Cub(B) \to Conj(\pi_1(B,b))$ such as $[p:E \to B] \to [p_{\ast}(\pi_1(E,e))]$

where $Cub(B)$ is the set of class of isomorphism of covering spaces over $B$, and $Conj(\pi_1(B,b))$ is the set of classes of conjugation of subgroups of $\pi_1(B,b)$.

So $\pi_1(S^1 \times S^1)=\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$ and its abelian.
So the $Conj(\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z})$ are the subgroups of $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$.

but since they are asking the 3-sheeted covering.

I have found that there are two possibilities:

$A=<(3,0),(0,1)> =\{(3m,n), m,n \in \mathbb{Z}\}$ and $B=<(3,1),(0,1)>$

such as $r_1: \mathbb{R}^2/A \cong S^1 \times S^1 \to \mathbb{R}^2/\mathbb{Z}^2 \cong S^1 \times S^1$ and for $r_2: \mathbb{R}^2/B \cong S^1 \times S^1 \to \mathbb{R}^2/\mathbb{Z}^2 \cong S^1 \times S^1$.

is it possible for $C=<(0,1),(0,3)>$ ?

Am I missing another covering space of 3-sheetes of $S^1 \times S^1 $.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I believe your $A$ and $B$ are the same subgroup: $(3,0)\in B$ because it is equal to $(3,1) - (0,1)$ and similarly $(3,1)\in A$. Your $C$ is the same as $\langle (0,1) \rangle$ so does not have index $3$, maybe you meant $C' = \langle (1, 0), (0,3) \rangle$ which does have index $3$. I feel like $A$ and $C'$ are the only two subgroups that have index $3$ in $\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}$ but I haven't come up with a rigorous argument yet.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there are 4 such subgroups. The other 2 are generated by $\langle(3,0);(1,1)\rangle$ and $\langle(3,0);(2,1)\rangle$.

Comment: thanks guys! What do you think would be a rigorous prove? what else should I consider to mention?. Thanks @SteveD

Comment: You can prove this by finding all epimorphisms to $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$ (there are 8) and then quotienting out by the action of $Aut(\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z})$.

Comment: epimorphism from where? what do you mean quotienting out by the action Aut, how does the action works? thanks @SteveD

Comment: For a group $G$, normal subgroups of index $n$ give you epimorphisms to a group of order $n$ (they become the kernel). This is not a 1-1 correspondence though, because you can always compose your epimorphisms with an automorphism of the quotient. I suggest you send some time thinking about this in the very easy case of $G=\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$.